# Cannot cut the leading zeros in my ip_adress

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, ip

That function should remove leading zeros from IPv4 addresses. The address `007.006.02.90` should for example be transformed to `7.6.2.90`. It seems like the problem is this line:

```
public static String zero_cutter(String ip) {
    String ipnew;
    String []  spliti = ip.split(".");
    int[] myArray = new int[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        myArray [i] = Integer.parseInt(spliti [i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        spliti [i]  = Integer.toString(myArray [i]);
    }
    ipnew = spliti [0] + "." + spliti [1] + "." + spliti [2] +    "." + spliti [3];

    return ipnew;
}
```

Comment: ``split`` takes a regex as the parameter. the ``.`` is a special character in regex. Use ``split("[.]")``.

Answer (score 7):

You must escape the `.` character in the pattern as dot is a special character which matches any character (as per [`java.util.regex.Pattern` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

> **Predefined character classes**
>
> . Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

One way to do it is to use `\\` in the pattern:

```
String[] spliti = ip.split("\\.");\
```

However you can replace your code with [`InetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) class:

```
String ip = "007.006.002.090";
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
System.out.println(addr.getHostAddress()); // 7.6.2.90
```

Comment: Escaping is probably cheaper than my answer that uses character classes. This is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

`split` takes a regex as the parameter. the `.` is a special character (=any character) in regex. Use `split("[.]")` to actually split the string at every period.

A shorter way of writing this method is this by the way:

```
return Arrays.stream(ip.split("[.]")).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(".");
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the split operation accepting a regex, here's an (as yet untested) regex-based solution.

```
public static String zero_cutter(String ip) {
    return ip.replaceAll("(?<=^|\\.)0+(?!\\.|$)","");
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution does not validate the IP address given nor check if it is `null`.

Comment: Not bad! The original code doesn't do any checking or validation either, so this is fine!